# How to find and use specific cell

Tags: c#, excel, datagrid, max

I have an excel file with a column of names and a column of numbers.

I had imported the excel into the Datagrid and manage to find the maximum number among from the  column.

For example, the cell which is the maximum is at (x,y).

How do I get the program to know the cell and display the name in the same row?

Comment: for excel manipulation which library are you using ?

Comment: Including some code of what you are trying that far could actually help us

Comment: Change title, remove intro info and added punctuation and line break.